# Клиент-сервер (php, android - приложение)

Tags: php, java, android, веб-программирование

Как из приложения на телефоне выполнить `php` скрипт, который расположен на компьютере? На `php` - веб сервер. А `Android` -клиент.
Как нужно связать телефон и компьютер?

```
public  void postExample(String url, String query) {

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Post Example");
        //устанавливаем соединение
        URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
        //мы будем писать POST данные в out stream
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        Log.d(TAG, conn.toString());
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        out.write(query);
        out.write("\r\n");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Log.d(TAG, out.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "super");

        //читаем то, что отдал нам сервер
        String html = readStreamToString(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        Log.d(TAG, html);
        request = html;
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage());
        Log.d(TAG,e.getClass().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: обращаетесь по http на ваш веб-сервер и php выполняется, что из этого вызвало трудности?

Comment: Я так и делаю. Вот мой запрос , где 192.168.169.1 - IP моего компа, с которого я раздал wifi . через connectify hotspot postExample("http://192.168.169.1/Web_Service_First/server.php", str);

Comment: она не проходит эту строку  
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");

Comment: Оно у вас с ошибкой падает? Если да - приложите лог. Возможно вы пытаетесь в сеть залезать из основного потока. Так на андроиде нельзя.

Comment: оно выдает 
29:34.309 25549-25549/deynega.webservicefirst D/-----------------------: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><method>list1</method></root>
03-30 19:29:34.309 25549-25549/deynega.webservicefirst D/-----------------------: Post Example
03-30 19:29:34.309 25549-25549/deynega.webservicefirst D/-----------------------: com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://192.168.169.1/Web_Service_First/server.php

Comment: Я поставил логи в классе которой выше PostExample. и по catch ничего не вывелось

Comment: Сам android изучаю "второй день".... http://kb4dev.com/article/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql-and-json

Comment: Зачем делать это через post? Как правило API идет через GET

Comment: у меня в задании сказано отправить запрос POST через Http используя xml over http

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы работать с mysql нужна написать для него на php api.

Пример гипотетического api: 
File: api.php

```
<?php
  if ($_GET['action'] == "getbalance") {
    $balance; //Узнаём из базы данных баланс аккаунта и записываем в переменную balance

    echo $balance;
  }
?>
```

Так мы отправляем http запрос на сервер и получаем ответ

```
http://mysite.ru/api.php?action=getbalance
```

**action** - переменная, **getbalance** - значения которое присваивается переменной.

Как отправить http запрос на java думаю найдешь.

Данный лучше выводить в json или xml для более удобной обработки данных.

Comment: у меня в php файле все описано и работает когда я отправляю тот же запрос с java на этом же компе. Вся проблема в том, что я не могу с телефона обратиться к файлу php. для связи использую Openserver